Cloudwatch logs return empty array using nodejs aws sdk

I am using aws javascript v3 to fetch cloudwatch logs.
My code runs fine without any error but I am still not getting any log events in response. 
Although when I open AWS console I can see events for the given log group in given region.
Here is my code
const timestamp = new Date();
const startTime = timestamp.getTime();
const params = {
    startTime: startTime,
    filterPattern: "test",
    endTime: new Date (startTime - 60 * 60* 24 * 1000).getTime(), // Last 1 day
    logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/mygroup',
    limit : 10
}

const events = await cloudWatchLogs.filterLogEvents(params).promise();
console.log(`results: ${JSON.stringify(events)}`);

Can someone help me out with what I am doing wrong with my code?
thanks
I expected proper log events to show up for the query.
